# How to load part of a big texture on another texture in three.js?

Tags: three.js, webgl, sprite, texture-mapping

I need to render a texture as a library of small parts, then copy each part to a set of different textures used in the scene. I think this is fundamental and I cannot find documentation specifically in three.js. Should I seek a solution in pure WEBGL, or is there a three.js solution?

EDIT:
One "solution" would be to set the UV coordinates of the target mesh (plane, whatever) to correspond only to the desired part of the big texture, but that would definitely be very inefficient, as it would require for each small mesh to load the whole big texture a huge waste of memory and GPU power as the whole big texture would be probably transformed multiple times(!), aside the inconvenience of setting the different UV coordinates on each mesh object. 
So, I'm looking to copy and assign only a small part and occupy in memory and process only that part for each mesh.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Let's say you're making a south park style character generator and you want one texture for the face so you want to draw the eyes, noes, and mouth into a single texture. The way to do that is to use the [Canvas 2D api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) and then use a THREE [`CanvasTexture`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/textures/CanvasTexture) to upload it. If you change the canvas then set the `needsUpdate` flag on the `CanvasTexture`.

Comment: Modifying the UVs is actually the correct way to go here. Your assumption about the meshes needing to load the texture individually is incorrect. You can create a single material with the texture and use it when creating ALL of your meshes. Only one texture instance will upload to the GPU, and the rest will reference it. Because the meshes have different UVs, they will respond uniquely to the texture.

Comment: @gman I need to render a bunch of H.Q text labels on a single big texture with a single pass, then copy those parts to several small textures in order to use them on various labels on the scene. 
The text rendering should be antialiased. If I could copy a rendertarget to a datatexture, then use WEBGL texSubImage2D() to copy an arbitrary rectangle to a smaller texture (because three.js' equivalent copyTextureToTexture has bugs and doesn't work). But then, I won't have the GPU's antialiasing of a screen rendering.

Your sugg. seems attractive, can I render antialiased on canvas off-screen?

Comment: @TheJim01  On a second thought, I think you're right about memory, but how about the transformation, would it transform only the visible part, or the whole texture for each different object?
There is still the antialiasing issue, the text rendered on a render target is not as H.Q as on the screen. Except if antialiased rendering on canvas can be done off-screen.

Comment: **1)** UVs aren't transformations, they are percentage references. A UV of `0.5, 0.5` references a point in the exact center of the texture. The shader/GPU will sample the texture (hence why they are called `sampler2d` objects in GLSL) to derive the correct color for the fragment from within the defined UV space. **2)** Three.js does not perform anti-aliasing for render targets. You can, however, use post-process anti-aliasing. Look in the [examples](https://threejs.org/examples) for FXAA, SSAA, SMAA, and TAA.

Comment: @TheJim01  Thanks for the reply, I'm trying to avoid expensive post-processing, except SSAA which I have already implemented and in some cases is better than the extremely complex SMAA. I want to see if the text can be rendered in H.Q even when full-screen post-processing is not an option.